# Getting the x axes unit in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to get the x axes units on my matplolib graph but can't seems to make it work.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {"x":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15], 
        "y":[10,20,30,40,150,145,165,200,210,230,240,143,134,4,234]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)

range_ = [0,100,200,300]

group1 = data.loc[()]
group1 = group1.groupby([pd.cut(group1['y'], range_)]).mean()
group1.x.plot()
plt.show()
```

The units should be the bins defined in `range_`. The `y` units work but not the `x`.

Please help !

Answer (score 1):

Before plotting, you could convert the bins to `str`:

```
group1.index=group1.index.astype(str)
```

Which gives the following:

[image]

**But** note that that is going to plot the bins equidistantly, regardless of their values.  So you could instead do something like plotting the values against the upper edge of the bins (or lower), and then format with the bins.  The following produces a similar graph to above, but will handle variably spaced bins better:

```
group1 = data.loc[()]
bins=pd.cut(group1['y'], range_)
group1 = group1.groupby(bins).mean()
group1.index = [i.right for i in group1.index]
group1.x.plot()
plt.xticks(range_[1:], bins)
plt.show()
```